# Error getting $_POST parameters

Tags: php, post, parameters, yii

I'm stuck with this. Turns out i am using a JUI dialog for the user to input a required password. This is the code of the view which is called by the JUI dialog:

```
<div class="passwordRequestDialog">
<?php 
$form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
                                'id'=>'requestpassword-form',
                                'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
                                'clientOptions'=>array('validateOnSubmit'=>false),
                                'htmlOptions'=>array('enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'),
                        )); 
?>

<div class="row">   
    <?php echo CHtml::activeHiddenField($model,'idLiga_hidden',array('value'=>$model->id)); ?>
    <?php echo CHtml::label("Ingrese la contrasenia de la liga $model->id?",false, array('style'=>'{font-weight:bold;font-size:12px;}')); ?>
    <?php echo CHtml::activePasswordField($model,'password',array('value'=>'')); ?>
</div>

<div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton("Guardar"); ?>
</div> 

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
</div>
```

However, when i click on the submit button, i can see with firebug the post parameters:

this    LigasDeAmigos%5BidLiga_hidden%5D=2&LigasDeAmigos%5Bpassword%5D=typedInPassword

Out of despair, I have tried to get the post parameter in many different ways:

```
$password = $_POST['this']['password'];
$password = $_POST['this']['LigasDeAmigos']['password'];
$password = $_POST['this']['LigasDeAmigos[password]'];
```

None of them work... the first one returns always the same value: "L". I am assuming it is getting the first letter out of the whole "this" parameter. The second one gives an error and so does the third one. Any help is more than welcome!

**Edit** as suggested by @Jon
print_r($_REQUEST) output

```
Array
(
    [idLiga] => 2
    [this] => LigasDeAmigos%5BidLiga_hidden%5D=2&LigasDeAmigos%5Bpassword%5D=pass
)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do a `print_r($_REQUEST)`. This will help you immediately, and you might also want to paste the results here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't know why the parameters are getting in like this (haven't done this particular scenario) so I can't suggest a solution that strikes at the heart of the problem (assuming there *is* a problem).

However, you can parse the parameters yourself like this:

```
// Normally this would be $form = $_POST['this'], but for the example...
$form = 'LigasDeAmigos%5BidLiga_hidden%5D=2&LigasDeAmigos%5Bpassword%5D=pass';

parse_str($form, $vars);
print_r($vars);

// You can now access the variables as in:
$id = $vars['idLiga_hidden'];
$password = $vars['pass'];
```

**[See it in action](http://www.ideone.com/hJ7AB).**

Comment: Continously saving my life! thank you very much worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

I would tie it to a [model](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.model).

Using your fields in your view, for example, your model would resemble:

```
class TestForm extends CFormModel
{

    public $id;
    public $password;
    public $idLiga_hidden;

    public function rules ()
    {
        return array (
            array ('password', 'required'),
            array ('id, idLiga_hidden', 'verify'),
        );
    }

    public function verify ($attribute, $params)
    {
        //$this->addError('idLiga_hidden','Incorrect dumaflache');
    }

}
```

Note that you need to define some 'rules' for the attribute assignment to work.
Then, you can reference the model in your controller:

```
public function actionTest ()
{
    if (isset ($_POST['TestForm']))
    {
        $model = new TestForm();
        $model->attributes = $_POST['TestForm'];
        echo $model->password;
    }
    else
    {
        $model = new TestForm();
        $this->render ('test', array ('model' => $model));
    }
}
```

Comment: The way @Jon suggested was simpler to implement, since i lost so much time with this, i used his solution. Thank you very much though!